# What is the difference between float() and toFloat() in GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine

There are too methods in gee to cast an image to float : `toFloat()` and `float()`.

They have the same documentation which is the following :

> Casts the input value to a 32-bit float.

Is there any difference between the 2 functions?

This question can be extended to all casting method that usually exist in 2 versions (`int()`, `toInt()` ...etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toFloat()` and `float()` are exactly the same, and this is true for all the other band type cast operators like `int()` and `toInt()`. You can use either ones, but if you're looking for a recommendation, I'd say to always use the ones with `to`, to be a little more specific about what they're doing.

(It happens that the versions without `to` prefixes came first and the prefixed ones were added later, but the precise rationale for adding the second set of names has been forgotten. Of course, it'd be simpler to have only one set now, but since both are in use, removing either would break some scripts without much benefit.)